# How do I filter a Django model by an attribute of a relationship field?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to query my 'Profile' model by the 'username' attribute of its OneToOneField relation 'User'.

I have attempted to accomplish this by setting my queryset using: Profile.objects.get(owner.name = ...), however in doing so I get an error saying 'SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?'. This is confusing as if I set this these parameters to something like 'id = ...', I get no such error.

What am I doing wrong here? If I wanted to query the 'Profile' table by the 'username' of its 'owner' relation, how would I best do this?

I have attached my code below.

**models.py:**

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = CharField(max_length = 80)

class Profile(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField('User', 
related_name = 'profile', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py:**

```
class UserProfile(generics.GenericAPIView, 
mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Profile.objects.filter(owner.username=username)
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:username>/profile/', views.UserProfile.as_view()),
]
```

Thanks

Comment: `owner__username=username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
 Profile.objects.filter(owner__username=username)
```

Instead of this

> Profile.objects.filter(owner.username=username)

Comment: I changed it to this and am now getting the following error: 'AssertionError: Expected view UserProfile to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.'

Comment: Did you use **double underscore**??

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups):

**Field lookups**

> Field lookups are how you specify the meat of an SQL WHERE clause. They’re specified as keyword arguments to the QuerySet methods filter(), exclude() and get().

> Basic lookups keyword arguments take the form field **__** lookuptype=value. (**That’s a double-underscore**).

For example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__lte='2006-01-01')
```

translates (roughly) into the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_entry WHERE pub_date <= '2006-01-01';
```

So, in your case, you try to filter by 'username' property on the field 'owner', that should be:

```
return Profile.objects.filter(owner__username=username)
```